# How to alter the recursive locking behaviour of Windows Mutex?

Tags: c, windows, posix, mutex

Windows Mutex seems to allow an acquired lock to be acquired again (recursively) if the thread currently owning the lock tries to acquire it.

But, posix based pthread locks don't allow such a behaviour.

Is there any compile time macro or any settings which can make the windows mutex behave in the same way as the pthread mutex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you program in Windows, avoid reimplementing the behavior of its Mutex.  It being re-entrant by the same thread is absolutely essential for its defined behavior.

A sync object without thread affinity is a semaphore that counts to 1.  Use CreateSemaphore().

Fwiw, it is very curious that you need this kind of behavior.  It sounds like you are trying to use the same sync object in multiple places inappropriately.  You can use the semaphore but you'll lose concurrency potential.  Consider using more than one mutex instead.

Comment: Actually, I have this problem related to come legacy code and I want to resolve it without changing much of the logic. So, wanted to know if the behaviour can be altered. 

My code should work in multiple OS, so I want the behaviour to remain same across all the OS.

"It sounds like you are trying to use the same sync object in multiple places inappropriately." - Yes. It is case of negative scenario. I just want the behaviour to be same in all OS in the negative scenario. 

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Well, use a boost semaphore.  Multi-platform and non-reentrant.

Comment: You may want to use non-recursive mutex to synchronize tasks (for example to implement a barrier between N tasks). In add there is ton of reasons to consider recursive mutex harmful and avoid.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot alter the fact that Windows Mutexes are recursive.  And while Posix threads are not recursive by default, you *can* use [`pthread_mutexattr_settype()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html) with the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` flag to make one so.

Locking a mutex in Windows is actually quite an expensive operation, and best suited to inter-process synchronisation.  For a mutex used only within a single process, a critical section is normally used, however these are re-entrant also.  As nobugz states, you would need to use a semaphore, initialised with a maximum count of 1, to get non-recursive synchronisation.

A semaphore object is like a special counter, that can be atomically incremented and decremented across threads (or processes, if created shared).  By creating one with a maximum count of 1, you get the non-recursive behaviour you require.

- [MSDN: Critical Section objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: Semaphore objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685129%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Critical Section CAN be entered again from the same thread. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682608(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for catching that oops - fixed answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [Read/Write locks (aka SRW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937.aspx). Unlike Windows Mutex, they are not recursive. But like Critical Sections, they are lightweight and do not call into the kernel if they are free ([Benchmarks](http://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex)).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article under ['fast mutex'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810047.aspx#locks__topic7).

These type of mutexes cannot be recursively acquired.

Off course, you'd have to look into how to implement them in C.

Comment: The Fast Mutex support is intended for drivers, not user-mode code.