# Can a Windows CRITICAL_SECTION object be configured to deny recursive access?

Tags: winapi, critical-section

By default, a CRITICAL_SECTION object is recursive. Can this behaviour be configured like a pthread mutex to enable or disable recursive thread access?

To clarify in response to the comments: I am referring specifically to a Windows CRITICAL_SECTION object, not a Windows mutex.

Comment: By recursive do you mean that it has a counter (like the reference counter in smart pointers)?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988324/how-to-alter-the-recursive-locking-behaviour-of-windows-mutex

Comment: @AlexFarber, A Mutex is a different thing from a critical section.

Comment: The point is that if you don't want a recursive lock, you need to use a mutex

Comment: Not clear what your goal is here; are you trying to detect attempted recursive use to flag it as (potential) error, for example? You could add your own code to do this for critsects that your own code owns, by pairing each one with a 'in use' bool; or for debug-only code, you could [dig into the critical section internals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) to check its state.

Comment: I see that you want only exact answer, at it is: no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it cannot. Documented APIs do not mention this in any way. Windows critical sections always accept recursive access.

> When a thread owns a critical section, it can make additional calls to EnterCriticalSection or TryEnterCriticalSection without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a critical section that it already owns.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/critical-section-objects

Answer (score 4):

A Critical Section always allows recursion within a thread.  So does a Mutex.  That is by design and cannot be changed.

A Semaphore, on the other hand, can prevent recursion within a thread.  See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129.aspx) for more details.