# Same critical section being called in function and subfunction

Tags: c++, multithreading, critical-section

I'm working as a support engineer, and in the dump of a failing process, I see that there are some locks.

Using Windbg (Visual Studio is not able to handle the call stacks correctly) I've found that one function (`ClassName::F()`) is coming back. That function uses a critical section and calls for a subfunction (`ClassName::f_sub()`), who's calling the same critical section, in a nutshell:

```
int ClassName::f_sub(){
  EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  ...
  LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  return ...;
}

int ClassName::F() {
  EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  ...
  int temp = f_sub();
  ...
  LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  return ...;
}
```

Every time it's the same critical section `m_cs` (a property of `ClassName`) being used.

In my opinion, this makes following sequence possible:

```
Thread 1 : F()     : Enter the critical section. (Thread 1 is in)
Thread 1 : f_sub() : Enter the critical section. (Thread 1 is in)
Thread 1 : f_sub() : Leave the critical section. (Thread 1 is out)
Thread 2 : F()     : Enter the critical section. (Thread 2 is in) 

=> WRONG! Thread 2 should be forced to wait for Thread 1 leaving the critical section via F().
```

Is my analysis correct and does this mean that it's advised to have different critical sections for main and sub functions?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117687/can-a-windows-critical-section-object-be-configured-to-deny-recursive-access

Comment: Recommended read: [How to properly leave a Critical Section?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29984941/6610379)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my analysis correct and does this mean that it's advised to have different critical sections for main and sub functions?

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-entercriticalsection) (emphasis mine):

> After a thread has ownership of a critical section, it can make
>   additional calls to EnterCriticalSection or TryEnterCriticalSection
>   without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from
>   deadlocking itself while waiting for a critical section that it
>   already owns. The thread enters the critical section each time
>   EnterCriticalSection and TryEnterCriticalSection succeed. **A thread
>   must call LeaveCriticalSection once for each time that it entered the
>   critical section.**

So no, what you described should not happen. It is perfectly fine to enter the critical section multiple times and it is required to leave it exactly as many times.

Comment: Re, "...[the same thread] can make additional calls to EnterCriticalSection..." There's a name for that. It's commonly known as a _[reentrant lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)_